# Find a function on R that is only discontinuous at these points given 100 distinct points.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Given $100$ distinct points $a_1, a_2, · · · , a_{100}$ in $\mathbb R$.
>
> (i) Find a function on $\mathbb R$ that is only discontinuous at these points.
>
> (ii) Find a function on $\mathbb R$ that is only continuous at these points.

My answer for part $(ii)\ $is $$f(x) = \begin{cases}(x-a_1)(x-a_2)(x-a_3)...(x-a_{100}) &\text{ if } x\in \mathbb Q\\0& \text{ if } x\notin \mathbb Q \end{cases}$$

How to do the first part?

Comment: Your idea for the second part nearly works for the first. Just let $f$ be $1$ on $Q$ instead of $0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^{100}(x-a_i)}$$

Answer (score 0):

For the first, let $f= 1_{\{a_1,...,a_{100}\} }$.

For the second, let $f(x) = 1_\mathbb{Q}(x) \cdot \min_{k \in \{1,...,100\}} |x-a_k|$.